# How to configure test run with Appium for native mobile Flutter app (C#)

Tags: c#, flutter, appium, appium-android, appium-flutter

I am starting automation on Appium for native Flutter mobile app.

I made all required preconditions and setup: prepared and run Appium Server, install and run Flutter driver (as default appium driver AndroidUIAutomator2 does not launch Flutter native app, though it is possible to install and remove app), prepared Client in Rider with specifying AppiumOptions in code.
But AppiumOptions that I have found on different-internet-resources do not allow to run Flutter app.
Maybe there are some additional options needed to be specified?

string apkPath= "/app-debug.apk";

```
    AppiumOptions capabilities = new AppiumOptions();
    
    capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "android");
    capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:platformVersion", "11");
    capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:deviceName", "Pixel 5 API 30");
  
    
    _driver = new AndroidDriver<FlutterElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
```

Comment: I have discovered addional options, that are required to launch and control Flutter app via Appium:

  capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:automationName", "flutter");
  capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:app", apkPath);

With these capabilities everything starts working.